# Time-sensitive encrypt / decrypt bug from PHP to Java, via URL encoding

Tags: java, php, encryption, encoding

I have an access-controlled PHP system that HTTP redirects clients to a Java-based reporting system with a unique security model (it's awful). To get around the report security model I'm using a Tomcat filter to validate all requests before they reach the reporting system. I'm using an encrypted token passed from PHP to Java which tells the reporting system who the client is. The filter checks the requested report name against a restricted list and returns a 403 if the client's role is insufficient.

The encrypted token stores a timestamp and the user's role, e.g.

```
1365549482|SysAdmin
```

When encrypted it looks something like this

```
vSEFgBYd30Ik5p4PZlG968cvdg==
```

The PHP system acts as a proxy for all reporting requests. When a user requests a report the request goes to PHP, which generates an encrypted token, URL encodes it, then appends it to the report URL and makes the GET request to the reporting system. My Java filter decrypts the token, pulls it apart, and figures out what to do.

9 times out of 10 this is fine, but occasionally the token cannot be properly decrypted. The above (unencrypted) example is converted to something like this

```
1365549482q??YZ7
```

And everything goes wrong.

I'm a bit out of my depth with encryption, decryption, and the particulars of character encoding, but unfortunately I'm the only developer available to work on this. Any thoughts at all on what might be going wrong here would be hugely appreciated. I don't expect any big code changes as it works most of the time, but there is clearly a time-sensitive component in the mix that I don't understand. Code snippets below

**EDIT**

I've spent a while debugging this now and it just got stranger. I wrote a small Java program to request a token from PHP via HTTP GET. The PHP script returns the same (URL-encoded) value that is passed to Java via a URL parameter in the normal workflow. The Java program decodes and decrypts this in the same way as the code snippet below and checks the result. Over thousands of iterations (so far, and counting) it is working as expected. However, while this test is going on I can see the same failures happening in the filter's log file.

Whatever's causing this intermittent problem is seemingly related the Java class being a Tomcat filter or the data being passed by URL via Tomcat. Does this give anyone a hint as to what could be going on here? I'm so very confused right now.

PHP

```
$presentAsSeconds = time();

$message = strval($presentAsSeconds + Configure::read('Reporting.Authentication.ExpireInSeconds')) . '|' . $userDetails['role'];

return base64_encode(
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        md5(Configure::read('Reporting.Authentication.Key')),   // matches "the key" in Java function
        $message,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
        Configure::read('Reporting.Authentication.IVector')     // matches "the vector" in Java function
    )
);
```

Java

```
private String decrypt(String initial) throws Exception {

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(md5("the key").getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec initialVector = new IvParameterSpec("the vector".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, initialVector);
    byte[] encryptedByteArray = (new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64()).decode(initial.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] decryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(encryptedByteArray);

    return (new String(decryptedByteArray, "UTF8"));
}

private String md5(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

    return number.toString(16);
}
```

Comment: Character encoding ought not make any difference since the bar character is (just) less than 128, assuming your roles are just ASCII strings too, but do you know what encoding your PHP is using anyway? I think it's just base 64 encoding here too, not URL-encoding.

Comment: Another odd thing here is that you're using the bytes of the string representation of the MD5 hash of your key, rather than just the bytes of the MD5 hash of the key (!). But I guess that's consistent with PHP's MD5 hash function and how mcrypt reads it?

Comment: @Rup thanks for the input, the token is first base 64 encoded, but as this contains URL-special characters (e.g. '=') it must then be URL-encoded before being appended to the report request URL. I don't think URL-encoding is the issue here but thought I would mention it for completeness.

Comment: One thing worth looking out for is padding - if your padding schemes are inconsistent or unexpected, that can cause it to fail only sometimes.

Comment: @Patashu thanks, but can you elaborate at all? As I said I'm quite green in this area

Comment: @tomfumb Lots of encryption related algorithms expect their input and output to be in certain block sizes (like groups of 4 or 8 bytes), and if they are not it has to apply a 'padding' scheme so it is, and the padding scheme has to be honoured by any related decryption.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with your getBytes() methods - these use the default system character encoding, which is NOT the same across every JVM.  Use getBytes("UTF-8") instead.

Comment: Perhaps, but if the key or IV were being read wrong then the output would look nothing like the input rather than slightly corrupted.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the key uses all Ascii characters while the input uses some Unicode characters, in which case the key would be the same regardless of whether it was Ascii or UTF encoded while the input would be corrupted.  Admittedly this is a stretch, though.

Comment: Thanks @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, I've made the changes you suggested and so far I haven't seen the issue. I'll test vigourously tomorrow and hopefully never see it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in how you've used the mcrypt library in PHP and then you're base64 encoding the encrypted data? We've definitily had some issues doing something similar and dropped the base64 encode and it worked after that.

Can you use another method to pass the token instead of the url? Such as a cookie or auth header?

Here's a snippet of my encryption/decryption in PHP (I'm not great with Java) because I think your mcrypt isn't right.

ENCODING:

```
    $userObjectJson = json_encode($this);

    //encrypt the user session object
    $mcrypt = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, '');
    $_SESSION['iv'] = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($mcrypt), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $keySize = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($mcrypt);
    $key = substr(MYAWESOME_KEY, 0, $keySize);

    mcrypt_generic_init($mcrypt, $key, $_SESSION['iv']);
    $_SESSION['user'] = mcrypt_generic($mcrypt, $userObjectJson);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($mcrypt);
    mcrypt_module_close($mcrypt);
```

DECODING:

```
    //decrypt the user session object
    $mcrypt = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, '');
    $keySize = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($mcrypt);
    $key = substr(MYAWESOME_KEY, 0, $keySize);
    mcrypt_generic_init($mcrypt, $key, $_SESSION['iv']);
    $userObjectJson = mdecrypt_generic($mcrypt, $_SESSION['user']);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($mcrypt);
    mcrypt_module_close($mcrypt);
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but as I don't understand the security side so well I have to ask - could this explain why I'm getting inconsistent results? The most confusing part of this problem is why it works most of the time. Things seem to go wrong right before the `|`, at the end of the timestamp, so I assume that there is one (or more) combination of `n|` that screws with how the string is handled.